# Le donne rom... sono discriminati?

Tags: verbs, gender, agreement, past-participle, moods

In this [article from Sputnik Italia website](https://it.sputniknews.com/intervista/2021011510011137-nasce-il-partito-dei-rom-in-italia-troppo-odio-verso-di-noi/)
one can read:

> Oggi le donne rom sono doppiamente discriminate, per non parlare di quelle che vivono nei campi che sono discriminati il triplo.

Is there any reason why in the second part of the sentence it says *discriminati* instead of *discriminate*? I guess it's either a typo or a rule I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Welcome! No, I see no reason. It's simply a grammatical error.

Answer (score 5):

Simplifying the structure of your text, it could be rephrased this way:

> Oggi le donne rom sono doppiamente discriminate. E quelle che vivono nei campi sono *discriminate* il triplo.

In the second sentence above there is a verb, *sono discriminate*, conjugated in the passive voice.

As in this instance, Italian passive voice can be constructed with the verb *essere* used as an auxiliary verb and past participle of the verb as in these examples by the linguist Luca Serianni in his book *Italiano*, a quite complete Italian grammar book:

> (io) sono amato 
> (voi) sarete pregati 
> (tu) saresti giudicato.

All verb tenses that are costructed with auxiliary *essere* followed by past participle of the verb must have past participle gender and number agreed with the subject: there are no exceptions to this rule.

The subject of the second sentence above is the feminine plural pronoun *quelle*, so past participle must also be feminine plural. That is, it should be *discriminate* and not **discriminati*.